# How to set R Highcharter stock x-axis dates

Tags: r, highcharts

I am working with numerically wide data that is grouped by a date, each day just as stock data could be.  When using the R Highcharter stock graph, the plot is correctly grabbing the numerical values for the data points/line but the dates are all listed as January 1 1970.

This question was previously posed: [R HighCharter Stock Graph not correctly pulling dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568233/r-highcharter-stock-graph-not-correctly-pulling-dates)  but the method for working with the dates and successful uses the hc_add_series_time_values which is now deprecated in the Highcharter package.

Given a data set in R of:

```
date <- as.Date(c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'))
source <- c(21, 27, 38, 22, 33)
test <- data.frame(date, source)
```

I would expect the following:

```
highchart(type = "stock") %>%
hc_add_series(test$source, type = "line")
```

To produce the stock chart with the dates on the x axis.

I also reviewed [Highcharter plotBands, plotLines with time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573626/highcharter-plotbands-plotlines-with-time-series-data) thinking that there was a special casting that was needed for the date column but that did not produce the expected result either.

What is the correct process now that the time values function of the highcharter stock component are deprecated to have the x-axis accept the datetime values as datetime values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could change your data frame to a time series and still use `hc_add_series`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(xts)

test_xts <- xts(test[-1], order.by = date)

highchart(type = "stock") %>%
  hc_add_series(test_xts, type = "line") %>%
  hc_xAxis(labels = list(format = '{value:%b %d}'))
```

**Output**

[image: highcarter plot with date on xaxis]

**Data**

```
date <- as.Date(c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'))
source <- c(21, 27, 38, 22, 33)
test <- data.frame(date, source)
```

Comment: Actually, Highstock has datetime axis only so it is not necessary to set it.

Comment: @raf18seb thank you for pointing this out - I'll edit the answer and make the correction.

Comment: the use of the XTS package turned out to be the key here!  Nice job Ben, thank you for the assist!